# Karate framework variable usage

Tags: karate

I have this steps:

```
...
Then status 200
And match response.requests[0].request.url == "/endpoint"
And json body = response.requests[0].request.body
And match body == { "something": "something"}
```

To simplify, I tried to put `response.requests[0].request` in a variable called `request`:

```
...
Then status 200
And def request = response.requests[0].request
And match request.url == "/endpoint"
And json body = request.body
And match body == { "something": "something"}
```

I'm having the following error:

```
'request' is not a variable, use the form '* request <expression>' instead
```

I read the [documentation](https://github.com/intuit/karate#assert) and the use of `request` seems to be fine:

```
Given def color = 'red '
And def num = 5
Then assert color + num == 'red 5'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any question from myself that answer was not accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make this change:

```
* def req = response.requests[0].request
# other steps
* request req
```

We simply disallow `def request` (using `request` as a variable name) because a lot of newbie users get confused. The error message has worked 99.9% of the time for users to understand what the problem is, but I guess you fall in the 0.1% :)

Comment: Maybe I'm in the 0.1% that thinks that when we write "def something = " then something is in fact a variable or at least we expect an error message saying that request is a reserved word :)

Comment: @italktothewind I acknowledge that this can be improved, so it will be so in the next version of Karate: https://github.com/intuit/karate/commit/fcd03edb3d3e9a682bb66533b0b68469c586b59b